# Proper code but can't insert to database

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, insert

I have a Visual Basic project using Access database.I run a query but i don't see any new data on my database table.I don't have any exception or error.Instead of this the success messagebox is shown.
Here is my code:

```
    Dim ID As Integer = 2
    Dim TableNumber As Integer = 2
    Dim OrderDate As Date = Format(Now, "General Date")
    Dim TotalPrice As Double = 100.0
 Dim ConnectionString As String = "myconnectionstring"
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)


    Try
        Dim InsertCMD As OleDb.OleDbCommand

        InsertCMD = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Orders([ID],[TableNumber],[OrderDate],[TotalPrice]) VALUES(@ID,@TableNumber,@OrderDate,@TotalPrice);", con)
        InsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)
        InsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableNumber", TableNumber)
        InsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", OrderDate)
        InsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPrice", TotalPrice)

        con.Open()
        InsertCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Added New Order",
                        "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Something went wrong
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        'Success or not, make sure it's closed
        If con.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Close()
    End Try
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Is ID an autonumber column?

Comment: I tried both using autoincrement and not using it but none of them worked

Comment: Are you sure you are not updating a copy of the database? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515419/vb-net-access-db-insert-not-inserting-data

Comment: I opened the .accdb file from Microsoft Access i can't see any new data.I tried to set the "copy to output directory" property of .accdb file to "do not copy" but i have an exception that says that it could not find the .accdb file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of two things is happening: Either the data is not getting updated, or it's getting updated and you're missing it when you look for it afterward. ExecuteNonQuery normally returns the number of rows acted on. If it's zero, then it's possible it's failing without an exception. This might have something to do with a duplicate ID.

If it's inserting successfully, then you aren't seeing the new record for some reason. Maybe you're looking in the wrong place, or maybe the record isn't turning up in a query for some reason. I don't know of anything with "on duplicate update" by default, but if Access has that it could cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Dim ConnectionString As String = "myconnectionstring"

I use ADO with Delphi to connect to Access so maybe a bit different, but I imagine with a connection string like that you're probably not even connecting to the database let alone updating it.

con.Open() is probably a function that will return a result of some kind indicating success or failure of connection. Failure of the Open and ExecuteNonQuery commands may not result in exceptions being raised, in which case your success message will display whether connection is achieved or not. Exceptions aren't the only type of error. Usually if a function returns a result indicating success or failure you should query that in a conditional statement to determine whether to process or show error message. wrapping swathes of code in exception handlers is lazy and in many cases not useful.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible problem I could see is if the ID Field in the database is an auto increment field, otherwise it should work. Alternatively, I find the following method much simpler

Use a table adapter and data set to insert new data as follows

Me.OrdersTableadapter.insert(ID, tableNumber, orderDate, TotalPrice) 
'NB: the parameters of this method will be in sequence of your table columns
Me.OrdersTableadapter.Fill(me.Dataset.Orderstableadapter)